# Training set accuracy deacreases as set size increases

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

In order to learn more about Machine Learning algorithms, I am playing with some data I collected myself but I have a strange behaviour when used with my Neural Network algorithm...

My dataset is composed of data split into 3 different possible categories (say A is 5% of the dataset, B is 5% of the dataset and C is 90% of the dataset).

When I try with a "small" training-set (~1800 entries), my training-set accuracy is close to 100% (A:99% B:100% C:100% -> quite normal), but my cross-validation-set and test-set accuracy are very bad.

So I tried with a larger training-set (~12000 entries), and my training-set accuracy drastically drops (A:18%, B:28%, C:99%) and the test-set accuracy is indeed still bad.

Then I tried with a medium training-set (~5500 entries), and as expected the training-set is between the both previous results (A:45%, B:78%, C:99%) and the test-set accuracy remains obviously bad.

Do you know what may be the cause of such a result? Is my dataset missing qualitative features that could help it differentiate the 3 categories A,B and C or is there another underlying reason that may explain such results?

---

configuration of my current Neural Network just in case it gives some hints:

- hidden layers: 1
- number of activation units: twice the number of features
- lambda: 2.0

Comment: Are the proportions of A, B and C in the test data the same as the training set?

Comment: Yes, and I randomly split the original dataset in 3 dataset (Training, Cross-Validation and Test set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overfitting for class C because the dimension of the three training sets are very umbalanced (5%, 5% and 90%). This explains, first of all, the cross-validation and test-set low accuracy. Then, when the training set size increase, also the training set accuracy drops because having so many C items, they tend to dramatically modify the network weights, also if you use a small learning rate.

In other words, the weights modifications caused by training on classes A and B are substantially "forgot" by the network, because the modifications caused by training on class C are much more significant.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't though of that. So in order to avoid this problem I could try to have almost the same quantity of each category in the training set. Is there another interesting approach I should consider?

Comment: Yes, you must try to have more of less the same number of items for each class. Since the difference is so large, maybe the best solution is to both decrease the size of C and increase the size of A and B. If you cannot collect other real A and B items, you can try to create them artificially starting from those that you already have. Depending of the type of data you are working with, there are different ways to do this.

Comment: This solved the inequality between the 3 categories accuracy. My cross-validation and test set accuracy are still bad, but this is a totally different problem. Thank you for your suggestion and for the lesson ;)